# Rails 4 add new column or field in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.1, ruby-2.1

I try to add new column into existing model in rubyonrails.
How can I add single or multiple field into my existing model.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to add a new column then

run rails generator with Add[column]To[model] format followed by column

```
$ rails g migration AddBioToNameOfModels bio:text
invoke  active_record
create    db/migrate/YYYYMMDDHHMMSS_add_bio_to_name_of_models.rb
```

then run

```
rake db:migrate
```